# Does PostgreSQL's Statistics Collector track *all* usage of indexes?

Tags: postgresql, database-indexes

After taking over the DBA duties on a fairly complex database, I wanted to eliminate any indexes that are consuming substantial disk space, but not being used. I ran the following, to identify unused indexes, sorting to prioritize those that consume the most space on disk:

```
SELECT 
    schemaname,
    pg_stat_all_indexes.relname AS table,
    pg_class.relname AS index,
    pg_total_relation_size(oid) AS size,
    idx_scan,
    idx_tup_read,
    idx_tup_fetch
FROM  pg_class
JOIN pg_stat_all_indexes ON pg_stat_all_indexes.indexrelname = pg_class.relname
WHERE  
    relkind =('i')
ORDER BY size DESC
```

I was a little surprised at just how many large indexes appear not to be used, at all -- as evidenced by a 0 for the idx_scan column. Some of these apparently-unused indexes include a function call that does something pretty specific (as in the contrived example below), and appear to have been set up to assist with API functionality.

```
--not real index
CREATE INDEX foo_transform_foo_name_idx
    ON foo USING btree
    (foo_transform_name(foo_name));
```

My question, here, is whether the Statistics Collector captures *all* uses of a particular index, even if those indexes were scanned from a SQL-language function, or in some other way?

Comment: Read this section of docs [pg_stat_all_indexes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/monitoring-stats.html#MONITORING-PG-STAT-ALL-INDEXES-VIEW) and then from here [CREATE INDEX](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createindex.html): "All functions and operators used in an index definition must be “immutable”, that is, their results must depend only on their arguments and never on any outside influence (such as the contents of another table or the current time).  ...". Last but not least run `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` on a query that you expect to use the index.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These indexes have never been scanned. However, there are some other uses for indexes:

- they enforce uniqueness and other constraints
- they make `ANALYZE` gather statistics on indexed expressions

Use this query from [my blog](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/get-rid-of-your-unused-indexes/) to find the indexes that you can drop without any negative consequences:

```
SELECT s.schemaname,
       s.relname AS tablename,
       s.indexrelname AS indexname,
       pg_relation_size(s.indexrelid) AS index_size
FROM pg_catalog.pg_stat_user_indexes s
   JOIN pg_catalog.pg_index i ON s.indexrelid = i.indexrelid
WHERE s.idx_scan = 0      -- has never been scanned
  AND 0 <>ALL (i.indkey)  -- no index column is an expression
  AND NOT i.indisunique   -- is not a UNIQUE index
  AND NOT EXISTS          -- does not enforce a constraint
         (SELECT 1 FROM pg_catalog.pg_constraint c
          WHERE c.conindid = s.indexrelid)
ORDER BY pg_relation_size(s.indexrelid) DESC;
```

Comment: Thanks! For someone who stumbles onto this question, I'll emphasize a point that Laurenz Albe makes in the linked blog post: you want to check for index scans on your *production* database, since development databases are unlikely to have the same kinds of index usage.